# How to send user filled form to a particular mail id?

Tags: android, email, android-intent

how to read values from multiselectionspinner and display it in EXTRA_TEXT instead of "body of mail"?  Here's the code :                                                              please help me...........

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  MultiSelectionSpinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final String[] array = { "one", "two", "three", "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","f","g","h","i","j"};  
      spinner = (MultiSelectionSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);  
      spinner.setItems(array); 
      final EditText  textTo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      final EditText  textSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
      final EditText  textMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
      final EditText  textadd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
      Button  buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String to = textTo.getText().toString();
                String subject = textSubject.getText().toString();
                String message = textMessage.getText().toString();
                String add = textadd.getText().toString();


                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("message/rfc822");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of mail");

                try {
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }




}

        });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                String to = textTo.getText().toString();
                String subject = textSubject.getText().toString();
                String message = textMessage.getText().toString();
                String add = textadd.getText().toString();

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("message/rfc822");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{to});
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , message);
```

Not sure where you want the 'add' String, please elborate.

**EDIT**
 - In response to your comment. Use a + sign to 'connect' strings together.

```
                String to = textTo.getText().toString();
                String subject = textSubject.getText().toString();
                String message = textMessage.getText().toString();
                String add = textadd.getText().toString();

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("message/rfc822");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{to});
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , to + subject + message + add);
```

Comment: I want all four to be used in "body of mail".

Comment: Do you know how to read data from a spinner and display it with the other four? I have edited the code @Eran